# How to send Push Notifications to test iOS PushKit integration online?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pushkit

I have implemented PushKit. Now I want to get Push notifications. Is there nay way to get Push Notifications online as we have many online APNS services which accepts device tokens and .pem file to send remote notifications?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You can create your own php file.**

**Source** https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

**Use below structure to achieve your task.**

[image]

[image]

Use this simplepush.php file

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):

    
      $deviceToken = '1234567890123456789';
//

    
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'ProjectName';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';



$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'PemFileName.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
//  'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body

$body['aps'] = array(
                     'content-available'=> 1,
                     'alert' => $message,
                     'sound' => 'default',
                     'badge' => 0,
                     );

    

// Encode the payload as JSON
    
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Use below commands to create pem file and use it in above code

```
$ openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out PushCert.pem

# Convert .p12 to .pem. Enter your pass pharse which is the same pwd that you have given while creating the .p12 certificate. PEM pass phrase also same as .p12 cert.  
$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushKey1.pem -in pushkey.p12

Enter Import Password:

MAC verified OK

Enter PEM pass phrase:

Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:

# To remove passpharse for the key to access globally. This only solved my stream_socket_client() & certificate capath warnings.
$ openssl rsa -in PushKey1.pem -out PushKey1_Rmv.pem

Enter pass phrase for PushChatKey1.pem:

writing RSA key

# To join the two .pem file into one file:
$ cat PushCert.pem PushKey1_Rmv.pem > ApnsDev.pem
```

After that go to simplepush.php location and fire command -> php simplepush.php

This way you can test your push kit notification setup architecture.

https://zeropush.com/guide/guide-to-pushkit-and-voip

https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

[Download](https://drive.google.com/a/brainvire.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKaGxGZVV4X0Y0d3M/view)

**Updated with Swift 4 code**

```
import UIKit
import PushKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,PKPushRegistryDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

var isUserHasLoggedInWithApp: Bool = true
var checkForIncomingCall: Bool = true
var userIsHolding: Bool = true

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    if #available(iOS 8.0, *){


        let viewAccept = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
        viewAccept.identifier = "VIEW_ACCEPT"
        viewAccept.title = "Accept"
        viewAccept.activationMode = .Foreground
        viewAccept.destructive = false
        viewAccept.authenticationRequired =  false

        let viewDecline = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
        viewDecline.identifier = "VIEW_DECLINE"
        viewDecline.title = "Decline"
        viewDecline.activationMode = .Background
        viewDecline.destructive = true
        viewDecline.authenticationRequired = false

        let INCOMINGCALL_CATEGORY = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
        INCOMINGCALL_CATEGORY.identifier = "INCOMINGCALL_CATEGORY"
        INCOMINGCALL_CATEGORY.setActions([viewAccept,viewDecline], forContext: .Default)

        if application.respondsToSelector("isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications")
        {
            let categories = NSSet(array: [INCOMINGCALL_CATEGORY])
            let types:UIUserNotificationType = ([.Alert, .Sound, .Badge])

            let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: categories as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)

            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }

    }
    else{
        let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }


    self.PushKitRegistration()

return true
}
//MARK: - PushKitRegistration

func PushKitRegistration()
{

    let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
    // Create a push registry object
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {

    let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)

    // Set the registry's delegate to self

    voipRegistry.delegate = self

    // Set the push type to VoIP

    voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushTypeVoIP]

    } else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    }


}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
    // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server

    let hexString : String = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(credentials.token.bytes),
    count: credentials.token.length).map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joinWithSeparator("")

    print(hexString)


}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {

    // Process the received push

    // Below process is specific to schedule local notification once pushkit payload received

    var arrTemp = [NSObject : AnyObject]()
    arrTemp = payload.dictionaryPayload

    let dict : Dictionary <String, AnyObject> = arrTemp["aps"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>


    if isUserHasLoggedInWithApp // Check this flag then only proceed
    {

        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == UIApplicationState.Background || UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive
        {

            if checkForIncomingCall // Check this flag to know incoming call or something else
            {

                var strTitle : String = dict["alertTitle"] as? String ?? ""
                let strBody : String = dict["alertBody"] as? String ?? ""
                strTitle = strTitle + "\n" + strBody

                let notificationIncomingCall = UILocalNotification()

                notificationIncomingCall.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)
                notificationIncomingCall.alertBody =  strTitle
                notificationIncomingCall.alertAction = "Open"
                notificationIncomingCall.soundName = "SoundFile.mp3"
                notificationIncomingCall.category = dict["category"] as? String ?? ""

                //"As per payload you receive"
                notificationIncomingCall.userInfo = ["key1": "Value1"  ,"key2": "Value2" ]


                UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notificationIncomingCall)

            }
            else
            {
                //  something else
            }

        }
    }


}

//MARK: - Local Notification Methods

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification){

    // Your interactive local notification events will be called at this place

}


}
```

Comment: I am using the same .php file to send remote notifications. Now, I am getting remote notifications but not PushKit notifications.

Comment: yes I am done with the iOS code. I am getting apns remote notifications using the same script but not PushKit notifications.

Comment: Check my updated answer, i hope for PushKit you have done iOS side code like this way. APNS related code doesn't work with PushKit related code.

Comment: Does it worked? check updated answer with images, let me know if any query.

Comment: Yes It worked. I selected Apple Push notification Service (SSL) instead of VoIP Service. I recreated the certificate and was able to send PushKit notifications. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 13):

For me the easiest way is to use a dedicated app I've found on GitHub called [Pusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher). It has both macOS and iOS version, it's really easy to use and it simply works!

Comment: Its really easy app to send Push Notifications. Thanks. :)

Comment: super handy app! must have!

Comment: Pusher is a great tool and now pushing Voip Push works great.